# JPA Error compiling query when using Oracle objects within a query

Tags: jpa

The following JPA query doesn't compile -

```
SELECT a FROM CUSTOMER a WHERE a.activeCustomer = 'N' AND a.customerInfo.city IN :cityName ORDER BY a.customerId
```

where the table CUSTOMER in Oracle database has a base type - CUSTOMERINFO which in turn has various values such as - 
city
country

This base type CUSTOMERINFO is extended by LOCALBUSINESSCUSTOMERINFO and MNCBUSINESSCUSTOMERINFO and a few others.

I think this may be due to the fact that when I define the column in my entity I define it as follows -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER", schema = "DBA")
@Converter(name="CustomerInfoConvertor", converterClass=CustomerInfoConvertor.class)

public class Customer implements Serializable {

      @Basic
      @Convert("CustomerInfoConvertor")
      @Column(columnDefinition = "CUSTOMERINFO")
      private ICustomerInfo customerInfo;

}
```

I have tried this query using SQL and it works fine but using it from JPA (JPQL) throws compilation error.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have mapped your customerInfo as a basic, so it is a basic in JPQL.

The column is of an Object object type?

In EclipseLink 2.3 you can map this as an Embeddable and the @Struct annotation, and use an Embedded mapping from the Customer.  Does the customer table have other columns or is it a type table?  If it is a type table, then use the @Struct to map it.